# Performance tuning for single threaded execution

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection

We are currently using the following flags for a series of java executions:

```
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=3 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=31
```

but I find that users who request only 1 core are exhibiting higher than 100% CPU usage and believe this is due to multithreaded garbage collection (GC). I know that changing `-XX:ParallelGCThreads=3` to `-XX:ParallelGCThreads=1` will make this single threaded, but does anything else here need to change as well? I believe that we can get rid of `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` and `-XX:+UseParNewGC` when using a single thread, but can I safely leave the other parameters as they are or do they need to change as well?

Comment: First things first: was the decision to alter the JVM flags this way a decision which stemmed for actual performance problems?

Comment: It was a decision made long before I got here and various changes to the way JVM runs on our systems *were* made for good reasons (performance, playing nice with our job scheduler, etc.)

I am now trying to enter the picture and make decisions to optimize performance ... but I know little about java - hence the question!

Comment: What do you mean with "users who request only 1 core?" I think you need to elaborate a bit what you are actually trying to achieve here.

Comment: Suppose I want to use exactly one core. Requesting 3 GC threads would be more than that which is bad.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to minimize the number of cores utilized, at cost of application  throughput and responsiveness, you should use the serial collector, it is single-threaded, stop-the-world and thus does not run additional threads in parallel to the application itself.

Simply run with `-XX:-UseParNewGC -XX:+UseSerialGC`

Comment: Thanks, which of the other flags listed are still applicable/needed?

Comment: survivor and tenuring options are still applicable, but serial GC behaves differently compared to CMS, so you may have to re-tune them. you'll have to do measurements to see what works best.